# Function loops once, then returns

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, typescript

I have a function as so:

```
removeDuplicates(item: String, allForToday: Array) {
    let temp = allForToday;
    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (temp[i].indexOf(item) > -1) {
            temp = temp.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Which I call like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < lastWeekItems.length; i++) {
                allForToday = t.removeDuplicates(lastWeekItems[i], allForToday);
 }
```

the passed `lastweekItems[i]` is a string, and allForToday is an array of strings that look like this: `1;2;3`. lastweekItems[i] can then be for example `2` What I'm expecting is the entire array to be checked for each and every item, and if the item is found, the entry that it's found in is removed from the array,  but what I'm seeing is that only temp[0] is checked, and then the entire leftover part of the array is spliced, and returned empty (temp.length turns from 14 to 1)...

Comment: `1;2;3` This is not an array.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to splice the array you're working with, rather than using `filter` or something?

Comment: The end result needs to be a returned array, without the duplicates and I have no idea of how to use filter

Comment: FYI, `splice` changes the contents of the array it's operating on. So there's no point in using a return value. Also, arrays are references. So `temp === allForToday`. Modifications made to `temp` will also change `allForToday`.

Comment: oh, that's it, thanks @MikeC, now it almost works, after I realized it returns the elements it removed.

Comment: Rather than using `splice` to mutate an array, it's a **much** better idea to use things like `filter` to create a new one. If you don't know how to use filter, there's no time like the present. If you insist on using `splice` in a loop, try iterating backward to eliminate problems causing by the array changing out from under the for loop (besides reading the docs to see how it works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove the duplicates you can use a reducer like so:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

var newArr = arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  if(acc.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    acc.push(val);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

The newArr array will contain only the non-duplicate values.